# Using code_to_plan and target(..., format = "fst") in drake

Tags: r, drake-r-package

I really like using the `code_to_plan` function when constructing drake plans. I also really using `target(..., format = "fst")` for big files. However I am struggling to combine these two workflows. For example if I have this `_drake.R` file:

```r
# Data --------------------------------------------------------------------

data_plan = code_to_plan("code/01-data/data.R")
join_plan = code_to_plan("code/01-data/merging.R")


# Cleaning ----------------------------------------------------------------

cleaning_plan = code_to_plan("code/02-cleaning/remove_na.R")


# Model -------------------------------------------------------------------

model_plan = code_to_plan("code/03-model/model.R")


# Combine Plans
dplan = bind_plans(
  data_plan,
  join_plan,
  cleaning_plan,
  model_plan
  )

config <- drake_config(dplan)
```

This works fine when called with `r_make(r_args = list(show = TRUE))`

As I understand it though `target` can only be used within a `drake_plan`. If I try something like this:

```r
dplan2 <- drake_plan(full_plan = target(dplan, format = "fst"))
config <- drake_config(dplan2)
```

I get an `r_make` error like this:

> target full_plan
>   Error in fst::write_fst(x = value$value, path = tmp) : 
>     Unknown type found in column.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   You selected fst format for target full_plan, so drake will convert it from class c("drake_plan", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame") to a plain data frame.
>
> Error: 
>   -->
>   
>   in process 18712
>
> See `.Last.error.trace` for a stack trace.

So ultimately my question is where does one specify [special data formats for targets](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#special-data-formats-for-targets) when you are using `code_to_plan`?

### Edit

Using @landau helpful suggestion, I defined this function:

```
add_target_format <- function(plan) {

  # Get a list of named commands.
  commands <- plan$command
  names(commands) <- plan$target

  # Turn it into a good plan.
  do.call(drake_plan, commands)

}
```

So that this would work:

```
dplan = bind_plans(
  data_plan,
  join_plan,
  cleaning_plan,
  model_plan
  ) %>%
  add_target_format()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not convenient. Here is a workaround.

```r
writeLines(
  c(
    "x <- small_data()",
    "y <- target(large_data(), format = \"fst\")"
  ),
  "script.R"
)

cat(readLines("script.R"), sep = "\n")
#> x <- small_data()
#> y <- target(large_data(), format = "fst")

library(drake)

# Produces a plan, but does not process target().
bad_plan <- code_to_plan("script.R")
bad_plan
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   target command                             
#>   <chr>  <expr>                              
#> 1 x      small_data()                        
#> 2 y      target(large_data(), format = "fst")

# Get a list of named commands.
commands <- bad_plan$command
names(commands) <- bad_plan$target

# Turn it into a good plan.
good_plan <- do.call(drake_plan, commands)
good_plan
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   target command      format
#>   <chr>  <expr>       <chr> 
#> 1 x      small_data() <NA>  
#> 2 y      large_data() fst
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is helpful! I turned it into a function above.